# How to define configuration dependent properties in VS C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm really new to C++ and Visual Studio, I know there are `ifdef` and `ifndef` to do the conditional compilation. 
But my boss ask me to create 2 different configurations (similar to `debug` and `release`) to automate this. For example:

```
#if $(some_configuration_dependent_flag)
  // I can do something specific for only config1
#endif
```

I've already checked the configuration manager, but the dialog is only used to enable/disable the projects in the solution. Where and how to define the variable `some_configuration_dependent_flag` mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio allows per config pre-processor definitions.

Use menu Project/Properties (on right click + Properties on the project) to open the Property Page dialog

Then in C/C++ / Preprocessor, you find Preprocessor Definitions. You select the configuration you want to change, and can add or modify any definition.